# 配列の要素にtagの値を設定するにはどのようにすべきでしょうか

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, xcode7, uicollectionview

プログラミング初心者です。
現在スタンプカメラアプリを作成中です。
CollectionViewと配列に関しまして、質問させて頂きます。
質問内容は下記のとおりです。

質問：配列の要素にtagの値を設定するには、どのようなコーディングをすべきでしょうか。

CollectionViewと配列を用いて画像を20個ならべて、1つの画像をタップしたらCollectionViewが閉じ、画像を指定した座標に設置するという仕様を考えております。
この場合、各画像にtagの値と座標の値をあたえるといいのではと思っております。

配列のコードは下記のとおりです。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for i in 1...20 {
        imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "\(i).png")!)
    }
}
```

最初はstoryboardで各画像にtagの値をあたえようと思いましたが、配列を用いているため
storyboardでtagの値をあたえることができないと思いました。

storyboardのコレクションビューの様子は下記のとおりです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

20個の画像にtagの値をあたえるにはどのようなコーディングをすべきでしょうか。
また、storyboardで配列使用時20個の画像にtagの値をあたえる方法などありますでしょうか。
お手数をおかけいたしますが、ご教示願います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テーブルビューやコレクションビューを使用する場合は、通常そのようなtagを必要としない。これらのコレクションビュークラスはセルをNSIndexPathで指し示すので、これをそのままtagの代わりにする。

例えばセルを選択した場合にデリゲートで呼ばれるメソッド、

```
collectionView(_:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)
```

においても選択されたセルのindexPathが渡される。特に複雑なことをせず画像ファイルの名前に含む識別番号を0始まりにしていれば`indexPath.row`の値がその識別番号に対応する。

座標は必要になってから都度動的に計算するとよい。

Comment: アドバイス頂いたデリゲートメソッドを用いてindexPath.rowの値を利用することやfor文の1...20を0...19にするなどして、コレクションビュー内の画像を無事配置することができました。とても勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

まだ少しわかりにくいところもあるのですが、Storyboard上に複数同種のUIControlを配置した時にtagプロパティの値によってそれらを区別する、と言った使い方が念頭にあるのだと想定して、ご質問の内容を考えさせていただきます。

*質問：配列の要素にtagの値を設定するには、どのようなコーディングをすべきでしょうか。*
→tagの値を設定できるような要素を配列に入れてください。

と言うのが回答になるでしょうか。
「画像」というのがUIImageを意識しているのであれば、UIImageにはtagプロパティはありませんから、ご自分でtagプロパティを持つようなデータ型を定義されれば良いのではないでしょうか。

```
class MyImageItem {
    let tag: Int
    let image: UIImage
    //...座標などの情報もこのクラスに持たせると良いのかも知れません
    init(tag: Int, image: UIImage) {
        self.tag = tag
        self.image = image
        //他の情報を持たせるなら、その初期化...
    }
}
```

初期化の部分は、こんな感じになります。

```
    var itemArray: [MyImageItem] = [] //MyImageItemの配列を宣言

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        itemArray.removeAll()
        for i in 1...20 {
            //tagを指定しながら初期化
            itemArray.append(MyImageItem(tag: i, image: UIImage(named: "\(i).png")!))
        }
    }
```

今まで`imageArray[i]`で中身のUIImageを参照していた部分は`itemArray[i].image`と言った感じで書きなおすことになります。UIImageをパラメータとして渡して処理していた部分はMyImageItemを渡すように書き換えた方がわかりやすくなるかも知れません。

全然違うとか、他にも何かあればコメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: 以前参考書で、画像を使ったUIButtonのtagに値を入れてコーディングする演習がありまして、今回UIImageのtagにも値を入れられたら便利かなと思ったりしました。しかし、UIImageにはtagプロパティはないのですね(汗。お手数をおかけしてすみません。また、頂いたコードのイニシャライズ方法など勉強になりました。